# jUnit and ignore inherited tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I need to create a version 2 of an existing service endpoint.  In creating the unit tests, I realized the most efficient way to test the new code was to extend from the existing unit test class.

The setup, teardown, and stubbing methods were already completed and are pretty complex.  I don't want to copy them into the new unit tests for redundancy reasons and I cannot move them into a utilities class since there's some tightly coupled logic in some of the stubbing classes.

When I run my new unit tests I am seeing the inherited unit tests run as well, which is not what I wanted.  Has anyone been successful in inheriting from a base unit test without running any of its @Test classes?

Here's an example of my base class :

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyBaseClass extends TestBase {
   @Value("${test.foo}")
   private String foo

   // setup, teardown, stubbing to pull in data to run the tests AND then the tests themselves
}


@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyVersion2BaseClass extends MyBaseClass {
   /* JUST THE TESTS, NO SETUP/TEAR DOWN/STUBBING NEEDED
      AS THIS IS CONTAINED IN THE PARENT CLASS
   */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing all the setup/tear down/stubbing code into an abstract class.

Now my two versions of test just extend from the abstraction and all the administrative code is available to them.